# Querying SQL randomly given a specific condition

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have this news collection database, where cat1, cat2, etc are the category:

```
title     cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  catcount  new1  new2  new3  new4
title1     1     2      0     0      2        0    0     0     0
title2     0     2      0     4      2        0    0     0     0
title3     1     2      3     0      3        0    0     0     0
```

Now I want to randomly select title with any of its category that is non zero, for example `title='title3' cat2='2'` to do some processing that determines if this category is correct.
Then return the value to the corresponding `new2` (since we processed `cat2`), decrement the `catcount`, and set the `cat2` to zero since it has been processed.

The goal is to process all combination of titles-categories and write the result to `new`, except I read it randomly.
How do I query this in MySQL?

EDIT:
The end result should be like this:

```
title     cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  catcount  new1  new2  new3  new4
title1     0     0      0     0      0        1    0     0     0
title2     0     0      0     0      0        0    2     0     4
title3     0     0      0     0      0        0    2     0     0
```

Comment: Can you show us an example output please with example parameter(s).

Comment: `title     cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  catcount  new1  new2  new3  new4`

`title1     0     0      0     0      0        1    2     0     0`

`title2     0     0      0     0      0        0    0     0     4`

`title3     0     0      0     0      0        0    2     3     0`

I can't seem to write it here with proper formatting. Basically I want to take a random title and category combination, use an interface for the user to determine if this category is correct, then write the result to `new`. In the end all the `cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4` will be zero.

Comment: You can write a stored procedure to get this done.

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here :-(

Comment: So far my solution is:
SELECT 'title','cat1','cat1','cat2','cat3','cat4' FROM 'thisdatabase' WHERE 'catcount' <> 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

Which will return one random entry, which then I can randomize again between categories in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a pseudo-random number with the RAND() function of MySQL.

However, note that the entropy of this function is very low, so you should consider getting all the entries of your table, then do the processing that you explained separately, in your code.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way
>   to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between
>   platforms for the same MySQL version.

Comment: What you mean is to read any entries regardless if it's zero, then check if it's zero in my code?

I think the problem is the more process I have done, the more likely I get zero since all processed entries will be made zero, this will in turn make my program reading too many times from database.

This database will have 2000 something columns and 14 categories each, reading randomly until I don't find zero will be too slow.

Comment: Oh wait, I think you're on to something. I might be able to read the non zero `catcount`, then randomly read one in 14 categories, this will be a lot faster.

Comment: I do not really know what is the faster way to have this job done, I just wanted to warn you that MySQL alone is unefficient for tasks that need randomness, and I do not have the privileges to comment questions yet.

Comment: I know I was not asking to you ;)

Comment: What kind of processing do you have to be done on a given title/category?

Comment: I am making a chatbot where I ask the user, "Is this (title) belongs to (category)?". When the user choose yes, I put the value to the corresponding `new` to say that this is indeed the correct category, if the user choose no, I put zero.